# python nested for to retrieve css tags values

Tags: python

The tags from a web page are as follows:

```
<div class="lg_col MT5">
    <p>
        <span class="sp starGryB">4.4</span>
    </p>
    <p class="MT5 UC">
        <span class="gd10gb">141 Ratings</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

I am trying to retrieve the values `"4.4"`, and `"141 Ratings"` for all the div class values `"lg_col MT5"`.

The nested `for` loop that I use isn't working as expected. It seems as if the hierarchy of the tags isn't taken into account.

```
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HEADERS = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"}

def test_function():
    url = "http://www.burrp.com/chennai/search.html?q=buffet"
    source_code = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS) 
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for tag in soup.select('div.lg_col.MT5'):
        for tag1 in soup.select('span.sp.starGryB'): 
            try:
                print(tag1.string)
            except KeyError:
                pass
        for tag2 in soup.select('span.gd10gb'):
            try:
                print(tag2.string)
            except KeyError:
                pass

test_function()
```

`

The expected output is:  4.4 followed by 141 Ratings for each of the div tags in the webpage.

But the output is: All the *starGryB* values followed by all the *gd10gb* values as this happens over and over again.

Comment: There's no `starGryB` class in an example you posted. Is it a typo? Also, "does not work as expected" is not very descriptive. How *exactly* it work and what do you expect from it?

Comment: Yeah that's a typo. Thanks for pointing that out. The correction has been made. The class too has to be starGryB.

Comment: The expected output is:  4.4 followed by 141 Ratings for each of the div tags in the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tag.select` instead of `soup.select` if you want to look in just `tag` and not the entire `soup`.

Comment: thanks blender. :) using tag.select solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Not for points.**

This is another way to scrape it to avoid having to deal with loops.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HEADERS = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"}

url = "http://www.burrp.com/chennai/search.html?q=buffet"
source_code = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS) 
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

tags_1 = soup.find_all('span', class_='sp starGryB')
tags_2 = [tag.parent.parent.select('span.gd10gb') for tag in tags_1]
tags_3 = [tag.parent.parent.parent.select('a.gr24mb.UC') for tag in tags_1]

scores = [score.get_text() for score in tags_1]
ratings = [rating[0].get_text() if len(rating) > 0 else 'NA' for rating in tags_2]
names = [name[0].get_text().strip() for name in tags_3]

tags = zip(names, scores, ratings)
for a, b, c in tags:
    print a, b, c
```

Result:

```
Wild Amazon 2.9 27 Ratings
European Buffet NA NA
Flamingo 2.3 17 Ratings
The Holy Smoke 2.9 13 Ratings
Snow Park 2.6 14 Ratings
Dhabba Express 2.7 11 Ratings
The Yellow Chilli 2.7 6 Ratings
The Piano, The Savera Hotel 2.5 6 Ratings
Roasts & Grills, Green Park Hotel 2.3 6 Ratings
[Finished in 0.9s]
```